# vb.net Simultaneous db updates

Tags: database, vb.net

This is written in visual basic using a .mdb database on a shared drive with oledb connections.

Suppose I have a table with the following 2 records:

```
    |ID |NAME        |CITY     |
    |2  |John Smith  |Dallas   |
    |15 |Bob Johnson |New York |
```

Since oledb copies the table to a local dataset then sends it back to the db(`data.tables("Test").Rows.Add`), if 2 people try to simultaneously add a new record in the 3rd row slot, will this result in one of the records being lost? If so, how can I go about preventing this?

Side Note: There will be no access to edit existing rows, only adding new rows.

**Workaround**: So I did as suggested and setup a test program to loop and attempt to update the database 100 times with no buffer time between attempts. I had 2 computers run it at the same time. It did result in the data being lost for one of the programs when it tried to update at the exact same second, but it also produced an error. In the end it happened very seldom, only producing about 3 errors in total for each run of the program.

As my program will primarily be small scale, i couldn't see rewriting my entire program for MySQL and setting it up on a computer as i really just want the database file on a shared drive. In the end I was able to get it to work to where no data was lost by working it in  the catch block to reattempt the update if an error had been produced. Not a solution for large scale production, but it works for my purposes quite well.

Comment: why exactly will one of the records get lost? wont they both get added? it works on connections why have connections if that kind of stuff happens. You should try to run 2 versions of the same program with a loop that keeps doing the Add command and set a counter on both loops to 1000 maybe add like Thread.Sleep(5000) to both.. they probably still wont run at simultaneously. Try setting the count to like 1000000 that could make them both run together. Check in the end if you have all 2,000,000 records.

Comment: the reason im thinking one might get lost is because oledb copies the db to a local datatable. when you update it, it sends the local datatable back to the database. So if 2 people try to update at the same time one will obviously go first, but the second one would basically just overwrite the first one. At least thats how it seems.

Comment: how do you know the whole datatable gets sent? if this is like any SQL library you send to it.. and it sends to you only when you do a `SELECT` command, you mean it updates a local file on your computer with the database? is this `MS Access`?

Comment: Yea its a ms access database file that's on a shared drive. when the oledb connection is opened it does use a `SELECT` command to grab the table and stores it in a dataset variable. When you do the update comand it takes the dataset variable and sends it to the database file to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a reason why people in the industry do not use Access...in simple terms it is a shit database read about it on wikipedia.
My best bet would be to use MSSQL it makes things way easier trust me, even over a network (as long as you add an exception to the firewall of the server hosting the DB). Use MSSQL if u dont want migrane headaches then come back to us and tell us how it goes. Fairly easy to set up same same you set up for Access db in VB.
 Just saw that u found a work around,let's hope it's a lasting solution something u will use in future projects without problems